# Windows 8 doesn't tile the wallpaper properly

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I am using 3 monitors: 1200x1600 - 2560x1440 x 1200x1600. 
I downloaded a wallpaper that is 4960x1600 pixels and I want it to span across all 3 monitors. I used to be able to do this by using the "Tile" setting, but it's not working.

Here's what it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vQwf.jpg (saved as jpeg to reduce size). 
And, here's the setting screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moj1n.png

And, in case you are curious, here's the actual wallpaper http://hdwallpapersfactory.com/game/rage-video-game-desktop-hd-wallpaper-726283/

EDIT: I'd prefer not to use any 3rd party tools to do this.

Comment: Have you tried the "span" setting?

Comment: "I used to be able to do this by using the "Tile" setting"  What's changed since that worked for you?

Comment: @ShaneDiDona, I tried every setting. Didn't work

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I ran a bunch of windows updates, including updating from Win8 to Win8.1. Everything else stayed the same.